# Best way to implement a List(Of) with a maximum number of items

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I'm trying to figure out a good way of implementing a List(Of) that holds a maximum number of records.

e.g.

I have a List(Of Int32) - it's being populated every 2 seconds with a new Int32 item.

I want to store only the most current 2000 items.

How can I make the list hold a maximum of 2000 items, then when the 2001'th item is attempted to be added, the List drops the 2000'th item (resulting in the current total being 1999).

Thing is, I need to make sure I'm dropping only the oldest item and adding a new item into the List.

Ben

Comment: A programming language would be a useful tag at this juncture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `List(Of T)` instead of a different collection type, you can overload the `Add()`-method:

```
Public Class ListOf2000(Of T)
    Inherits List(Of T)

    Public Overloads Sub Add(item As T)
        MyBase.Add(item)
        If Me.Count = 2001 Then Me.RemoveAt(0)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
if(list.Count >= 2000)
    list.RemoveAt(0); 
list.Add(item);
```

Comment: I just fixed a small error there for you (as you add the item after checking the size)

Comment: @Justin, thanks for the fix. On my mobile, and not so easy to do the code parts ;)

Answer (score 2):

A queue structure is what you need. Add elements to the queue when they arrive. Only remove elements from the queue when the size > 2000

Answer (score 2):

You can use for instance a circular list (linked list with the 2000th item pointing to the first). Adding a new element adds a "next element" to the current pointer.

When you add the 2001th element it will replace the first one you have created i.e. the oldest one.

However it would aslo be interesting to know how you want to access the data in your structure.

Comment: Thanks (to everyone) for their responses. I'll look into how to create a Circular List (never heard of this before). The way I'll be accessing the data later is using a Linq query to find out if a particular Int32 number exists in the List. if it doesn't, it will be added.

Comment: A more generic term is "Circular Buffer": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Answer (score 0):

Circular array, with a pointer to begin and end. If you are using CPP u could use `dequeue`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Queue. But it does depend on how you need to access those in the list/queue.